# mysql, one user deletes, another updates, who will win?

Tags: mysql

Question is about mysql transactions.

```
create table tbl1(
    id integer,
    val integer,
    primary key (id)
);
insert into tbl1 (id, val) values (1,2);
```

I created two users who work simultaneously.

```
USER1                                         USER2
start transaction;

update tbl1 set val = 3 where id = 1;

                                      delete from tbl2 where id = 1 and val = 3;

commit;
```

As a result the row will not be deleted. How to fix it? I want that the row will be deleted, because delete query come later than start of the transaction of first user.

EDIT: actually row will be deleted, so there is no explanation why it is the case.

Comment: This is very, very bad design. You should lock your tables before doing anything of such a critical nature.

Comment: @slugonamission could you explain more please

Comment: If you want to ensure that nobody can modify your table while another transaction is happening, you should use the `LOCK TABLE` construct in order to make all other transactions wait until the first transaction has finished, otherwise you create a pretty nasty race condition.

Comment: @slugonamission Is table locked in standard `update` querry ( without `begin ... commit` surroundings)?

Comment: No, it's a separate construct. See paulsm4's answer for more details, and have a read of the MySQL manual about the `LOCK TABLE` construct.

Comment: @slugonamission please see edit to the post

Comment: Again, no, this is wrong. You need to ensure mutual exclusion by using `LOCK TABLES`.

Answer (score 3):

@capoluca - you've got a [race condition](http://www.celticwolf.com/blog/2010/04/27/what-is-a-race-condition/).  There's no simple, one-size-fits-all answer that can resolve it.

- In your current code:

  a) the delete won't be made if it occurs *before* the update

  b) the delete will be "undone" if it occurs *during* the transaction

  c) the delete *will* be made if it occurs *after* the "update" transaction completes
- One solution is to lock the table.

  This isn't necessarily portable to all databases, and can have a devastating impact on performance.
- Another solution is to simply "not worry about it". This can actually be a legitimate choice, depending on your business requirements.  And it might work perfectly well if the "deletes" are part of a batch job - in which case the record(s) in question should definitely get deleted sooner or later.
- Yet another solution is to put *both* the update *and* the delete in their own, separate, transactions

Please look at the link I cited above and see what makes most sense for your situation.

Comment: thank you, great answer, putting `delete` in its own transaction is what I need. I thought that atomic operations like 'delete', 'update' are considered as a transactions itself, but it is not, otherwise putting 'delete' in its own transaction will not help.

Comment: I cannot understand, I have just repeat code in my post, as result table is empty, is there need to put `delete` in its own transaction?

Comment: The term for "considered as transactions itself" is "auto-commit", discussed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html.  the link also discusses variations like "START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT" and "AND CHAIN".  "Autocommit" is per-session.